# How to run .cmd file as task in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have `.cmd` file that I want to include everytime build.gradle is run by Android Studio.

Let's say the filename is `create-artifacts.cmd` and so in my module's `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    ...

    task createArtifacts(type:Exec) {
        commandLine = ["create-artifacts.cmd"]
        workingDir = file("$rootDir")
    }
}
```

How may I be helped with this?

Answer (score 1):

See the [ExecTask documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)

```
task createArtifacts(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'create-artifacts.cmd'
    workingDir rootDir
}
```

Comment: actually i don't want to specify the directory because the project might be transferred or pulled by another developers from the repo so I want to run it from `$rootDrive/create-artifacts.cmd` rather than `c:\this\is\an\example\directory\create-artifacts.cmd`. In your example, you're running it from `C:\create-artifacts.cmd`, am i correct?

Comment: So use `commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "$rootDrive\\create-artifacts.cmd"`

Comment: I got this error: `Error:(31, 0) Could not get unknown property 'rootDrive' for task ':app:createArtifacts' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.
<a href="openFile:C:\sample\directory\DemoApp\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>`

Comment: Seriously? it's you that said you have a `$rootDrive` variable... I'm just copying you!!!